# Android Умирает сервис после закрытия основного приложения

Tags: java, android

Я изпользую pusher.com (https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java).

Проблема следующая я создал сервис и прописал там код пушера для получения пушев в фоновом режиме, но как только я закрываю основное приложение (MainActivity) сервис умирает.

В поисках проблемы я попробывал запустить обычный цикл for в новом потоке в сервисе и о чуда при закрытии основного приложения цикл также умирал.
Я думаю pusher по дефолту создает соедининие в новом потоке.
Тогда я после кода подключения пушера создал бессконечный цикл while и при закрытии основного приложения сервис и пушер продолжил работать!
Но как это сделать "по нормальному" без бесконечного цикла?

На api 24 все работает и без циклов, возможно система просто прибивает сервис, но почему...

Код:

```
//MainActivity
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

```
//MyService
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster("eu");
    Pusher pusher = new Pusher("apikey", options);

    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                Log.i("Pusher", "State changed from " + change.getPreviousState() +
                        " to " + change.getCurrentState());
            }
           @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                Log.i("Pusher", "There was a problem connecting! " +
                        "\ncode: " + code +
                        "\nmessage: " + message +
                        "\nException: " + e
                );
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);
    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");
    channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
                Log.i("Pusher", "Received event with data: " + event.toString());
            }
        });
/* Тот самый while  с которым все работает
      while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
*/

   return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicServ.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), serviceIntent);
```

Надо использовать `startForegroundService`. Если просто смены методики старта не помогает, изучите полный гайд как сделать `ForegroundService`
https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/